# Compare Network logs with const using Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to see if request is triggered when I scroll down the page.
I cannot use RequestURL because of timestamp. I know that there is RequestLogger.

What I'm trying to do is:

- create const which contains part of request URL, get specific log
- from Network tab in Dev-Tool in Chrome (maybe filter them) compare
- log with const to see if it contains the same pattern.

And if they begin with the same pattern pass the test

Comment: Here is an example of using RequestLogger: [https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html#log-http-requests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html#log-http-requests). Could you please clarify if you faced any issues with this approach? Is it applicable to your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys. Here is a workaround:

```
const logger = RequestLogger(new RegExp(`somestring`));
```

Then I use

```
await t.expect(logger.requests.length).eql(1);
```